converting tuple to variant problems
I need to access a value in std::tuple by index at run time. For that purpose I wrote a function that returns a std::variant with the same types initialized for the specified index. Implementation involves recursive template instantiations:
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_n = [](/*tuple-like*/auto&& t, std::size_t index)
{
    using variant_type = decltype(std::apply([](auto&&... v){
        return std::variant<std::monostate, std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(v)>...>{};
    }, t));

    constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>;

    if constexpr(N > size)
        return variant_type{};
    else 
    {
        if(N == index + 1)
            return variant_type(std::in_place_index<N>, std::get<N - 1>(t));
        else
            return get_n<N + 1>(t, index);
    }
};

constexpr auto tuple_to_variant(/*tuple-like*/auto&& t, std::size_t index)
{
    return get_n<1>(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t), index);
}

I'm using c++23 compilers. The problem is that only gcc compiles without errors. The clang and MSVC compilers go into infinite instantiation loop. Is that a bug in compilers? How can I fix this code that it compiles in all three compilers?
Here is Compiler Explorer demo

You might be able to adapt this

Succeed to make clang pass and ICE from gcc and fail from MSVC Demo. Next is to make only MSVC succeed ;-)

@Jarod42 -- what a horror story, all compilers are broken, they just have different trigger points.

Works if you use
template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto get_n(/*tuple-like*/auto&& t, std::size_t index)

instead. There's no reason for get_n to be a lambda.

So this is a bug in compilers after all, there is no reason why a standalone function would work and lambda wouldn't. Kudos to GCC for getting it right. P.S. the reason it was lambda because originally it was inside tuple_to_variant function, but then I had to make it template and take outside.

@Gene I'm not sure, it depends on how the standard is worded. Could also be that gcc is accepting code that it shouldn't.

Since you're calling the lambda recursively, this is only possible with a C++23 explicit object parameter. This should work:
constexpr auto get_n = []<std::size_t N>
  (this auto self, /*tuple-like*/auto&& t, std::size_t index)
{
    using variant_type = decltype(std::apply([](auto&&... v){
        return std::variant<std::monostate, std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(v)>...>{};
    }, t));

    constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>;

    if constexpr(N > size)
        return variant_type{};
    else 
    {
        if(N == index + 1)
            return variant_type(std::in_place_index<N>, std::get<N - 1>(t));
        else
            return self.template operator()<N + 1>(t, index);
    }
};

constexpr auto tuple_to_variant(/*tuple-like*/auto&& t, std::size_t index)
{
    return get_n.operator()<1>(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t), index);
}

Demo

yes, I came to the same realization

They're not calling the lambda recursively, get_n<0> calls a different lambda get_n<1>

And this is another possible solution that is accepted by every compiler. The advantage is that the lambda function is local inside tuple_to_variant, so it doesn't create any names in outer scope.
inline auto tuple_to_variant(auto&& t, std::size_t index)
{
    constexpr auto get_n = []<auto N>(this auto&& self, auto&& t, std::size_t index, std::index_sequence<N>)
    {
        using variant_type = decltype(std::apply([](auto&&... v){
            return std::variant<std::monostate, std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(v)>...>{};
        }, t));

        constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>;

        if constexpr(N > size)
            return variant_type{};
        else 
        {
            if(N == index + 1)
                return variant_type(std::in_place_index<N>, std::get<N - 1>(t));
            else
                return self(t, index, std::index_sequence<N + 1>{});
        }
    };

    return get_n(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t), index, std::index_sequence<1>{});
}

Code Explorer demo

A none-recursive implementation with verbose types would be:
constexpr auto tuple_to_variant(std::size_t i, auto && t)
{
    using ref_t = decltype(t);
    using tuple = std::remove_cvref_t<ref_t>;
    constexpr std::tuple_size<tuple> size;
    return [&t]<std::size_t ... j>
    (std::index_sequence<j ...>, auto i) {
          using variant = std::variant
                        < std::monostate
                        , std::remove_cvref_t
                        < std::tuple_element_t<j, tuple> > ...>;
          constexpr std::array dispatch {
              +[](ref_t& lvalue_) {
              return variant 
                   { std::in_place_index<1 + j>
                   , get<j>(static_cast<ref_t>(lvalue_)) };
              }... ,
              +[](ref_t&) { return variant{}; }
          };// dispatch;
          return dispatch[i](t);
    }(make_index_sequence<size()>{}
    , std::min(size(), i));
};// tuple_to_variant;

I like to put the active/operating/selecting argument(i) first and passive argument(t) last.
